# My Fusion Tables won't style the way I want them to, even though I followed the Fusion Tables sample code. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to control what colors my map is, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I followed [Google's sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#fusion_table_styles), but to no avail. My code is below. The attempt to style the map starts at line 132. The comments are just helpful hints for me, since I'm just getting my feet wet in JavaScript and Fusion Tables API.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    #map-canvas { width:800px; height:600px; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var layer;

     var cz = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -95),
        zoom: 4 
     };

     var locationColumn = 'geometry';
     var tableRegion = 4437529;

     var mapStyle = [
        {
          featureType: 'all',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { saturation: 99 }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.arterial',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.local',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.country',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.locality',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.neighborhood',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { visibility: 'off' }
          ]
        }
      ];

     var map_options = {
      center: cz["center"], //Accesses the 'center' property of the 'cz' object
      zoom: cz["zoom"], //Accesses the 'zoom' property of the 'cz' object
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, //Type of map.
      zoomControlOptions: { //control options for the 'zoom' action of Google Maps
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL, //Makes the zoom function on the upper-left-side of Google Maps small -- instead of a scale-like thing, it's just a plus and minus
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER //Puts Zoom function center-left
      },
      streetViewControl: false, //Turns off Street View option
      panControl: false, //turns off the circular pan button in nupper-left
      mapTypeControl: false //Turns off 'MAP/SATELLITE' option in upper-right
    }; 

     var locationQuery = {
      select: locationColumn,
          from: tableRegion
     };


     function initialize() {
      //new Google Map with the 'map_options' 
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), map_options);

      //Styles the map so it removes roads, saturates things, etc. See 'mapStyle'
      var style = mapStyle;
      var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(style, {
        map: map,
        name: 'Styled Map'
      });
      map.mapTypes.set('map-style', styledMapType);
      map.setMapTypeId('map-style'); 

      //Makes the Fusion Tables layer, querying the polygon location info
      layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: locationQuery,

    //Here's where I try setting the colors and conditions for my map. Doesn't work.
    styles: [{
      polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: "#FFFFFF",
        fillOpacity: 0.5
      }
    },{
      where: "price > 200",
      polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: "#FFFF00",
        fillOpacity: 0.5
      }
    }]
      });
      layer.setMap(map);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may have been an issue with FusionTables.  It didn't work for me either when I tried running it locally (I got the tiles with the dreaded "Data May Be Still Loading, Drag or refresh the page to find out"), when I finally got around to [uploading a copy](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_styleEx_unmod.html), it worked, but then it worked locally as well.

Comment: Interesting. I asked a couple friends to try out the code the night I posted this question. They also reported seeing only "Data may still be loading." However, I just tried the code on another machine, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated what your exact problem is except it ain't working.  *Not very helpful.* So I'm guessing.
Your map worked fine for me.  No problems.  Try setting fillOpacity: 1 in the code below to see that it's working fine.  By using .5 you are allowing the base map colors to blend with the FT layer colors.

```
styles: [{
      polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: "#FFFFFF",
        fillOpacity: 0.5
      }
    },{
      where: "price > 200",
      polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: "#FFFF00",
        fillOpacity: 0.5
      }
    }]
```

Comment: Ah, I see now how my question was confusing and vague. I should have stated that the map wouldn't load. My apologies for that.